# null-aware operator ? not recognized

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I am trying to convert a single list into a list of 3 lists based on some filtering to create the view model.

Since a filter (`List.where`) may return null, I am trying to implement the null-aware (?) and the if-null (??) operator. However, this is flagged as `Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.` by the IDE.

So basically I am adding 3 `List<PropertyTask>`s to a `List<List<PropertyTask>>`, where each `List<PropertyTask>` is a filter applied on the initial `List<PropertyTask>`.

My code looks like this:

```dart
factory JobMasterEditViewmodel.fromDomain(JobMaster master)
    => JobMasterEditViewmodel(
    tasks: master.tasks == null
        ? null
        : List<List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>>
            .from([List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(((List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.always)))? // null-aware
                  .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))?) ?? []), // if-null
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel> // from here on without null-awareness
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.inventory))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                   => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.periodically))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.onRequest))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            ]),
);
```

Comment: Is the if-null flagged? Which specific section of code gets flagged by the IDE?

Comment: `(List<PropertyTask>.from(master.tasks.where((t) => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.always)))` has the error text. The `)` in `?) ?? []` flags `Expected to find ':'.`, which results from mistakenly understanding `?` as a condition and not as null-aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That list will never be null, so trying to make the code null-aware there results in the compiler misinterpreting it to mean the ternary operator. If you remove the null-awareness code, the error is removed as well.

If code cannot be null for any values inputted (which this cannot; [List documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/List/List.from.html) shows that it cannot return null), then trying to add null-aware code to it will result in the compiler being confused.

```dart
factory JobMasterEditViewmodel.fromDomain(JobMaster master)
    => JobMasterEditViewmodel(
    tasks: master.tasks == null
        ? null
        : List<List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>>
            .from([List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(((List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.always))) 
                  .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf)))), 
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel> 
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.inventory))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                   => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.periodically))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            List<JobMasterEditTaskViewModel>
              .from(List<PropertyTask>
                .from(master.tasks.where((t)
                  => t.taskType == PropertyTaskTypes.onRequest))
                    .map((tf) => JobMasterEditTaskViewModel.fromDomain(tf))),
            ]),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right. Somehow I assumed `.where()` would return `null` if it doesn't find anything. But I just checked on DartPad and it is `[ ]`. Maybe I should have questioned this assumption a bit earlier...